# TypeScript: self-referencing return type for methods in inheriting classes

Tags: generics, inheritance, static, typescript, self-reference

*Disclaimer: I'm finding it hard to summarise the problem in the title of the question, so if you have better suggestions, please let me know in the comments.*

Let's take the following simplified TypeScript class:

```
class Model {
  save():Model {
    // save the current instance and return it
  }
}
```

The `Model` class has a `save()` method that returns an instance of itself: a `Model`.

We can extend `Model` like so:

```
class SomeModel extends Model {
  // inherits the save() method
}
```

So, `SomeModel` will inherit `save()`, but it still returns a `Model`, not a `SomeModel`.

Is there a way, perhaps using generics, to set the return type of `save()` in `SomeModel` to `SomeModel`, without having to redefine it inside of the inheriting class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're in luck. [Polymorphic this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/4910) just came out in [TypeScript 1.7](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/typescript/archive/2015/11/30/announcing-typescript-1-7.aspx). Upgrade to TypeScript 1.7 and then remove the explicit return type and it will work perfectly:

```
class Model {
    save() {
        return this;
    }
}

class SomeModel extends Model {
    otherMethod() {
    }
}

let someModel = new SomeModel().save();
// no compile error since someModel is typed as SomeModel in TS 1.7+
someModel.otherMethod();
```

Comment: Thank you. Just upvoted your answer, because it answered the question... There is a twist though, one that I hadn't anticipated - I'll open a new question!

Comment: Here is the question with the twist: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34098023/typescript-self-referencing-return-type-for-static-methods-in-inheriting-classe

Answer (score 6):

I know I'm late to the party,
@2019 I found a way to make return type specific:

```
class Model {
  save<T extends Model>(this: T): T {
    // save the current instance and return it
  }
}
```

This way whatever extends `Model`, or `Model` itself, will be referenced as return type when called.

And with Typescript@3, this also works:

```
class Model {
  save(): this {
    // save the current instance and return it
  }
}
```