# Self-referencing return type for static methods in inheriting classes

Tags: typescript

With [Polymorphic this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/4910) in TypeScript 1.7, as I discovered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34095437/typescript-self-referencing-return-type-for-methods-in-inheriting-classes), we can define a method in a class with a return type of `this`, and automatically, any classes that extend that class and inherit the methods, will have their return types set to their respective `this` type. Like so:

```
class Model {
  save():this {    // return type: Model
    // save the current instance and return it
  }
}

class SomeModel extends Model {
  // inherits the save() method - return type: SomeModel
}
```

However, what I'm after is to have an inherited `static` method with a return type referencing the class itself. It's best described in code:

```
class Model {
  static getAll():Model[] {
    // return all recorded instances of Model as an array
  }

  save():this {
    // save the current instance and return it
  }
}

class SomeModel extends Model {
  // inherits the save() method - return type: SomeModel
  // also inherits getAll() - return type: Model (how can we make that SomeModel?)
}
```

Perhaps I'll have to think of a different way to implement this, since Polymorphic `this` in TypeScript 1.7 does not support `static` methods *by design*.

**EDIT**: I guess we'll see how this Github issue wraps up: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5863

Answer (score 56, accepted):

This is doable in TypeScript 2.0+. By using an inline `{ new(): T }` type to capture `this`, you'll get what you wanted:

```ts
type Constructor<T> = { new (): T }

class BaseModel {
  static getAll<T>(this: Constructor<T>): T[] {
    return [] // dummy impl
  }
  
  /**
   * Example of static method with an argument:
   */
  static getById<T>(this: Constructor<T>, id: number): T | undefined {
    return // dummy impl
  }

  save(): this {
    return this // dummy impl
  }
}

class SubModel extends BaseModel {}

const sub = new SubModel()
const savedSub: SubModel = sub.save()

// Behold: SubModel.getAll() returns SubModels, not BaseModel
const savedSubs: SubModel[] = SubModel.getAll()
```

Note that `getAll` still expects no arguments with this typing.

For more information, see https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#using-class-types-in-generics and https://stackoverflow.com/a/45262288/1268016

Comment: if you are using other static methods in the function implementation of `getAll` like `this.someOtherStaticMethod()` the provider will complain. You can go around this with `(this as any)`

Comment: @Flion every time you cast to `any`, you make Mr. Hejlsberg cry. You can create a `BaseModelClass` to capture the static signature rather than using the inlined `{ new(): T }` type. See https://github.com/Vincit/objection.js/blob/master/typings/objection/index.d.ts#L370 for a worked example.

Comment: thanks, I agree, better to make Mr Hejlsberg happy where possible :) .. the BaseModelClass works more neatly for most things. But I still have an issue with `this.someOtherPrivateStaticMethod()` within `getAll`. Interfaces dont allow private declarations, but I need to define it in the interface. If I define it public the compiler complains when I call `getAll` on a subclass that its private in one but not in the other

Comment: How do you get to other static methods, without casting to any? I have a base class, but i'd rather not make a big interface for my base class...

When I try to use this.otherStatic, it complains. 

If I use (<extends Base>this.constructor).otherStatic, it says I cannot convert this=>T to <extends Base>....

Comment: @RichardDuerr if you figure that one out, please share with the class! I certainly haven't. Because of that, all my TypeScript projects do *not* follow ActiveRecord-ish class class designs that heavily use class statics for code organization. I use scala-esque traits and composition, instead.

Comment: The trick was to NOT use this parameter, and instead ONLY use the line:

baseConstructor = (<extends BaseClass>this.constructor);

Comment: Any way to use this.someOtherStaticMethod() yet? am using alot of static methods?

Comment: This is a great answer! But is there a way to do this when `getAll` takes parameters? Or is that not possible?

Comment: @yalpsideman I just updated the code with an example for you.

Answer (score 47):

Based on the [simplest answer](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5863#issuecomment-528305043) to the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5863), you can use [`InstanceType<>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#instancetypet) like this:

```
class Foo {
    static create<T extends typeof Foo>(this: T): InstanceType<T> {
        return new this() as InstanceType<T>
    }

    static getAll<T extends typeof Foo>(this: T): Array<InstanceType<T>> {
        return []
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo { }

const a = Bar.getAll() // typeof a is Bar[]
const b = Bar.create() // typeof b is Bar.
```

Where I threw in the `create` function just for illustration, from the linked GitHub example.

Comment: Wow, I've been looking for this answer for a very long time. Thanks!

Comment: What would the solution be for a static getter, given that one can't take a parameter?

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Thanks

Comment: This was right on the money. Thank you. I agree, this SHOULD be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [Brains answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34098023/typescript-self-referencing-return-type-for-static-methods-in-inheriting-classe/59775495#59775495) you can get the **return type**, directly with just

`(typeof Class)['foo']`

### Example:

```
export class MyClass {
    myFunction(param:string):number{
        return typeof param === "string"?1:0
    }
                                             /** Just class['foo'] to normal methods */   
    static myStaticFunctions(cards: string): Parameters<MyClass['MyFunction']>[0] {
                        /** and *(typeof class)* ['foo'] to static methods */   
        const typedReturn: ReturnType<(typeof MyClass)['myStaticFunctions']> = "works"
        return typedReturn
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you expecting this static method to return in the inherited subclass? Is it something like this:

```
class A {
    private static _instances = new Array<A>();
    static instances(): A[] { return A._instances; }
    constructor() { A._instances.push(this); }
}

class B extends A {

    static instances(): B[] { 
        return <B[]>(A.instances().filter(i => i instanceof B)); 
    }
    constructor() { super(); }; 
}

var a = new A();
var b = new B();

console.log(
     "A count: " + A.instances().length + 
    " B count: " + B.instances().length);
```

This will output "A count: 2 B count: 1". Or what are you expecting?

Comment: He wanted his `getAll()` method to return an array of the subtype, without having to redefine the method in the subclass. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/42768627/1268016