# typescript return type of inherited class

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
class Base{
    clone(){
        //return new instance of the inherited  class 
    }
}

class Derived extends Base{
}

const d1=new Derived();
const d2=d2.clone; // I want d2 to be of type Derived
```

What should be the the return type of the clone method for d2 to be of type Derived?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I really hope there is a better way, but here is what I currently do:

```
class Base{
    clone(): this {
        return new (this.constructor as any)(); 
    }
}

class Derived extends Base {
}

class DerivedAgain extends Derived {

}

const d1=new Derived();
const d2 = d1.clone(); 
const d3 = new DerivedAgain().clone();
```

`d2` is of type `Derived`, and `d3` is of type `DerivedAgain`, as expected.

Comment: This is great. Thanks.

Comment: So simple, so efficient. +1

Comment: this works in your example but what if you want to return an array of instances of the inherited class? :this[] doesnt work

Comment: in TS 2.0, for returning an array of instances see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34098023/typescript-self-referencing-return-type-for-static-methods-in-inheriting-classe?rq=1