# How to create a child class in TypeScript using parent static method?

Tags: typescript, design-patterns, factory-pattern

I have two classes: Model and User. User extends the Model.

```
export Model {
  id: number;
  static fromData<T>(data: any): T {
    return Object.assign(new Model(), data);
  }
}

export User extends Model {
  name: string;
  sayHi(): string {
    return 'Hi, ' + this.name;
  }
}
```

The way I wanted to use it looks like this:

```
const currentUser = User.fromData(dataFromServer);
const message = currentUser.sayHi();
```

Method hi() doesn't work because I have created an instance of Model class.

**How to use TypeScript generics to get an instance of derived class using base class static method?**

I'm planning number of different entities with common.

I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45262288/669493) but I don't know how to pass parameters into a static method in my case.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Since the static method is on the class itself we have access to the class constructor using `this` inside the static method, `this` is the class iself. If we constrain the `this` parameter to the static method to be a constructor returning `T` (`this: new ()=> T` ) we will get correct typing for the return value. The `this` parameter is just for the benefit of the typescript compiler, it will not actually be emitted to JS and you don't have to pass it explicitly:

```
export class Model {
    id: number;
    static fromData<T>(this: new () => T, data: any): T {
        return Object.assign(new this(), data);
    }
}

export class User extends Model {
    name: string;
    sayHi(): string {
        return 'Hi, ' + this.name;
    }
}

const currentUser = User.fromData({ id: 10, name: ""});
const message = currentUser.sayHi();
```

Playground [link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=export%20class%20Model%20%7B%0D%0A%09id%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%09static%20fromData%3CT%3E(this%3A%20new%20()%20%3D%3E%20T%2C%20data%3A%20any)%3A%20T%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09return%20Object.assign(new%20this()%2C%20data)%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20class%20User%20extends%20Model%20%7B%0D%0A%09name%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%09sayHi()%3A%20string%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09return%20'Hi%2C%20'%20%2B%20this.name%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20currentUser%20%3D%20User.fromData(%7B%20id%3A%2010%2C%20name%3A%20%22%22%7D)%3B%0D%0Aconst%20message%20%3D%20currentUser.sayHi()%3B)

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know the syntax `this: new () => T`. Is there a documentation on this feature somewhere?

Comment: @Paleo It's a mix of several things, `this:` is the fact that you can specify the type of `this` on member functions https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3694. The `new ()=> T` is just a constructor signature, (similar to a function signature but callable with `new`). And the whole things works because of the way parameter inference works ..

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir, thank you very much for reply. I haven't seen usage of `this` in the Typescript manual. Do you have link or whatever to read more about the topic?

Comment: How do you call other static methods when using this? https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwDYEMDOa4FkIBNhJwDeAsAFACQaMKMAlgnAGZQQC2AIrSgDwAqcUDGAA7XJhz4kAPgAUMABZ00ALjgjgAdziyAlHAC80uH11qBpShSjAYAVygi4i5QDomECHoDc5CgF8-aloGZk9+QRBhMQk8AjkXVXUtHX0jEzMTYj9rWwcnDW1Enz9AsjLyUEhYRFQMOABVNGAoSOjxbDjCSwqyBAgRakQHGxEYJpbDRuaod1ZObhK+gbQIJGBXJAgAc1kEEdFxmd1vIA

Comment: That's awesome! 
I was trying to figure how to do it if I have a constructor. Any suggestion?
from function will look like `static fromData<T>(this: new (id: number) => T, data: any): T` 
but `return Object.assign(new this(id), data);` won't work, it has no access to the `id`.