# Typescript compiler shows different type from actual

Tags: typescript, types

I'm working on my own ORM for Postgres DB for my pet project. But I faced the problem that typescript thinks that there is a different type than actual I get. Here is the code:

```
//model.ts
export class TestModel {
  
  static tableName: string;
  constructor(data:any) {
    
  }

  public static async findById(id: number) {
    const client = await pool.connect();
    const result: QueryResult<any> = await client.query(
      `select * from public."${this.tableName}" where id = ${id}`
    );
    const results = result ? result.rows : null;
    client.release();
    if (!results) return null;
    return new this(results[0]);
  }

}

export class TestWeekModel extends TestModel {
  static tableName = 'Week';
  id: any;
  current_week: any;
  
  constructor(data: any) {
    super(data);
    this.id = data.id;
    this.current_week = data.current_week;
  }
}

//test.ts 
import { TestModel, TestWeekModel } from "./database/model";


async function test() {
    const week = await TestWeekModel.findById(1);
    console.log(week);
}

test();
```

The actual output is : TestWeekModel { id: 1, current_week: 2 }

but typescript says that the variable "week" has the type "const week: TestModel | null". Why does typescript think that week is TestModel type and not TestWeekModel? How can I get desired TestWeekModel type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the desired solution to the problem. So, here new code:

```
type Constructor<T> = { new (data: any): T, tableName: string }
export class TestModel {
  
  static tableName: string;
  constructor(data:any) {
    
  }

  public static async findById<T>(this: Constructor<T>,id: number){
    const client = await pool.connect();
    const result: QueryResult<any> = await client.query(
      `select * from public."${this.tableName}" where id = ${id}`
    );
    const results = result ? result.rows : null;
    client.release();
    if (!results) return null;
    return new this(results[0]);
  }

}

export class TestWeekModel extends TestModel {
  static tableName = 'Week';
  id: any;
  current_week: any;

  
  constructor(data: any) {
    super(data);
    this.id = data.id;
    this.current_week = data.current_week;
  }
}
```

After explicitly defining this, with creating a new own type, TypeScript correctly defines the type of week variable.
Here is the source of working code:
[Instantiating child class from a static method in base class, using TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45123761/instantiating-child-class-from-a-static-method-in-base-class-using-typescript/45262288#45262288)
[TypeScript: self-referencing return type for static methods in inheriting classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34098023/typescript-self-referencing-return-type-for-static-methods-in-inheriting-classe)

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript might be inferring the base class because `findById()` is defined there. A simple workaround would be using type assertation

`const week = await TestWeekModel.findById(1) as TestWeekModel;`

Another option would be to have the method return the result, and instantiate the new class on assignment.

```
// TestModel...
if (!results) return null;
return results[0];
// ..

async function test() {
  const result = await TestWeekModel.findById(1);
  const week = new TestWeekModel(result);
  console.log(week);
}
```

Comment: Oh, thank you very much. So there are no other options to get the desired result? The first solution is well, but I would like to make it somewhere inside classes, but not override methods or types in child classes.