# Cast an object to a model in typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a json like `lst` in below example, and I wanna map it to `MyModel`.

```
interface MyModel { 
    id: number;
    isRequired : boolean;
    ,...
}

let lstByModel: Array<MyModel> = [];

// lst comes from API
let lst:any[] = [
    {
        "id":"10",
        "isRequired":"false"        
    }
];

lstByModel = lst; // How to map lst to MyModel (lstByModel)?

console.log(lstByModel); // it shows { id : "10" , isRequired : "false"} but I need { id : 10, isRequired : false } How can I do that?
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`types` or `iterfaces` in Typescript are compile time only. So your `lst` will not be converted to any other `type` automatically.

You need to manually map string to number. In your case

```
lstByModel = lst.map(lstItem=>{
    return {
         id:parseInt(lstItem.id), // manually changing string to number
        isRequired: lstItem.isRequired=="true" //parsing boolean
    }
})
```

Comment: thanks for your answer.
How can I get type of property from interface? (for example: get `number` from interface to set for id)

Comment: Close this question if answered, post another question

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

> The `Object.assign()` method is used to copy the values of all enumerable own properties from one or more source objects to a target object. It will return the target object.

Answer (score 1):

if you can use classes for your models instead of interfaces, here's an Object.assign() pattern that might work for you.  also a good pattern for other api- or io-related translations / functionality.

```typescript
abstract class ApiLoadable {
 static fromObject<T extends ApiLoadable>(this: { new(): T }, obj: object): T {
   return Object.assign(new this(), obj);
 }
}

class MyModel extends ApiLoadable {
  id: number;
  isRequired : boolean;
}

const json = `{ "id": 10, "isRequired": false }`;
const model = MyModel.fromObject(JSON.parse(json));
```

notice there's a bit of 'this' parameter trickery in the static method -- this lets the static method always create the correct subclass instance, based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34098023/typescript-self-referencing-return-type-for-static-methods-in-inheriting-classe?rq=1) about that subject

Answer (score 0):

```
let lst:any[] = [ { "id":"10", "isRequired":"false" } ];
```

As shown in your json format, the **id** and **isRequired** fields is type of string.

Hence what you need to do is, convert **id** to number and **isRequired** to boolen using foreach loop.