# Passing self reference as parameter in abstract base class static function for use in child classes

Tags: typescript, inheritance, static

In typescript, one can create a base class that has a static function that child classes can use and that return whatever the type of the calling child class. This is shown here [TypeScript: self-referencing return type for static methods in inheriting classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34098023/typescript-self-referencing-return-type-for-static-methods-in-inheriting-classe).

```
type Constructor<T> = { new (): T }

class BaseModel {
  static getAll<T>(this: Constructor<T>): T[] {
    return [] // dummy impl
  }

  /**
   * Example of static method with an argument:
   */
  static getById<T>(this: Constructor<T>, id: number): T {
    return // dummy impl
  }
}

class SubModel extends BaseModel {}
const savedSubs: SubModel = SubModel.getById(1234)
```

How can one create a function that takes an input parameter of the type of the subclass though?

Psuedocode-wise it would look something like this:

```
static getByChild<T>(this: Constructor<T>, child: this): T {
  return // dummy impl
}
```

But this doesn't work. How can I agnostically make the method parameter be a subclass of this base class?

Comment: Note that you need some properties in `BaseModel` and `SubModel` so that they are [structurally distinct from the empty type](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-do-these-empty-classes-behave-strangely), otherwise you'll find weird behavior like `SubModel.getByChild(1234)` working, since `1234 extends {}` is true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `T` is intended to be the subclass instance type, as evidenced by `this` being `Constructor<T>`, then you just need to use `T` as the type of the `child` parameter:

```
static getByChild<T>(this: Constructor<T>, child: T): T {
  return child; // ?
}
```

And you can verify this works:

```
const oneSub = SubModel.getById(123); // SubModel
const anotherSub = SubModel.getByChild(oneSub); // SubModel
```

Hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwM7AE4FcDGw6oDwAqAfFALxQDeUCEA7gBQCUAXFAVAL4BQXmANgEMkSKACEhEALJwAJhD6UeUKACMJABVRwwZKACI4AawEg9SqCgHAAlpigBzCMACCfPoSL1gAC2tJW8MhoWDj4xCxsANoAuorKyqhO6KgIUDFQAPQZUDLoALZ5IFDWeWB8XMocUOYZAFS1Fcq1UACiAB4CpXzQcABmFsBWtlB5Tt6yULTWPlACqQKo9vkQCMDMjVC1GY2WNnaOwKIgAJIyHl6+-rCIKBjYuB4ANMUyrAj5KhCoEewUG1CJYDJVLvNwAQgA3I1uDtBnsHE4jjBfHwzsQLn4AjdgvcwkRnpgUa82D84vFAcCoITrKiIZlsgB+aFcGH8IQiADK6BU0jkCggbWAKxkInESCksnkZKQ3M02l0egEbgB1ns3mAZm4mGxUEQEC5Kl0Bt58gAdAcjqd6ABGABMAGZGHSslBjZLytqgrMEHAfF8DUbuSa+ObESBkTSZPQ9QanfTXUH3UA)