# Typescript: self referencing static class members

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

There is a [github issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5863) on [Polymorphic this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/4910) in static methods and also a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34098023/typescript-self-referencing-return-type-for-static-methods-in-inheriting-classe). These are discussing how to solve/work around the problem in case of static class methods. However I could not find any reference to solve this problem in case of static class members.
We have a model class and this class has a few static members containing maps where the keys are the model fields. We are using property decorators in the inherited classes to tag model fields (the inherited classes containing only field definitions). The decorator is also adding the fields to the static maps defined in the base class. See the code below and in [playgound](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.0-beta#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-kzEKgAB5QVBgFoAoFRAAC0xwuFRchA-PQMCxNyZhCpgn2oKZoOeHwDv3+oYjUZjkkBpQTSbwqfTmezPlEebNBfaoNEJb9nxo8MBOqMOLMABUq5Ho38AVZ9gSAI4gGDMEkAeQAtjAoFPZBrSFqF1Z-TQIRI4OhUCk3StRE0DeEGf8n6Z5aRlA7EE6rUTmGgRAfVQWggA)

```js
function field(): any {
    return function (target: Base, propertyKey: ModelFields<Base>, _descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {
        if (!target.constructor.fields) {
            target.constructor.fields = {};
        }
        target.constructor.fields[String(propertyKey)] = String(`s_${propertyKey}`);
    };
}

class Base {
    ['constructor']: typeof Base;

    static fields: Record<string, string>;
    // Actually the above is supposed to be Record<keyof ModelFields<this>, string> but 'this' is not allowed here
}

class A extends Base {
    @field()
    public propA: string = 'A';
}

class B extends Base {
    @field()
    public propB: string = 'B';
}

type ModelFields<T extends Base> = Required<Omit<T, keyof Base>>

console.log(B.fields) // B.fields type is not correct here
```

currently the static `fields` is defined as `Record<string, string>` but it doesn't tell what keys exists on it although we know that the valid keys are `keyof ModelFields<this>`. But obviously `this` is not allowed there.

Is there any solution to get the typing of `fields` right?

Comment: I wouldn't expect `this` to work in a `static` context.

Comment: ```this``` works in static context in case of functions. See the references in the post. The problem is that it is working in static functions but not in static getters or static properties.

Comment: Would a Singleton work here?

Comment: I'm not sure how would you use singleton here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some things you can do to get closer to your desired effect.

The first issue as you discovered is the lack of polymorphic `this` in static  members. We can replace the field with a method. On a method we can use the generic type to capture the call site type:

```
class Base {
    ['constructor']: typeof Base;

    static fields: Record<any, any>;
    static getFields<TThis extends typeof Base>(this: TThis)  {
        type I = InstanceType<TThis>;
        return this.fields as { 
            [P in keyof I] : string
        }
    }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.0-beta#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMGBTANgEwBQEoBciAhmAJ6IDeAsAFCL2IBOqUIjSoksCi2URjAOYtCAISIBnVABpEAB0Zw5qRlFIBpVKUIBZOJgwAxNFgkAecVIB8sgPoGJERjDlQ4jQgAVFy1aQAiqI7Oru64lLQMUYgQCBJQiBKkALYARnDoiAC8iAAGErYAJBQKSipqmqQAvrkA3JHR9DDAvACE-EIsAHSxYPGMINDuXSgYmBLh1HSN0R3CUD1xUANDjCMm49mUVfXTjVUNjXPdvf2DbmujpgDapb4VWgC6W0lpGbtRO7QHNLQQ6JIJIhLKgIntENcAOSnZbndyQx6ENTKOAtEG7Q6JfiwCDIDYSQgAJVQsUYmDMJFIsn6MDAgisHwY8SIOMQ82MY3MABUuQALGBA1AADygqDAm2RqFRwMkqCsfH5BMQPMV4TBM0QksQAEkttq+vxIKguaRlGYVQKGZiosxWOxNYr1pziECKIhrTNrp5ELTEABrLTS7XPQg0uke+g-T7fP4AiRAgCCiGFovFQJB6oYAAErjhcJi5CBUugYLi7gnQ8taYItpCE5Ddj9Y4DgcmRWLNhmplEcxs8AWiyWyz5RJXnHTa6IG7RMczWaL4nhM0dHbmJJifk2aFq9AZ0BzTOa26nO7KrFtiQBHEAwZjkgDyyRgUHNsgDpGlIKs54AZFjx4IM40DCxBbGAqAAO6IAm-bAUsiCpGBkHAkuQGnBkqBdOgcCCHwppSi0RCyJK0qpLICZdOy+J4LIoiUSwB7jHguBAA)

The other problem is that there is no way to filter members based on a decorator (these are not represented in the type system). What you could do is add a brand to the type all fields that have the decorator and filter the fields on that brand:

```
class Base {
    ['constructor']: typeof Base;

    static fields: Record<any, any>;
    static getFields<TThis extends typeof Base>(this: TThis)  {
        type I = InstanceType<TThis>;
        return this.fields as { 
            [P in keyof I as I[P] extends FieldBrand<unknown> ? P : never] : string
        }
    }
}

declare const fieldBrand: unique symbol;
type FieldBrand<T> =T &  { [fieldBrand]?: never }
type UnBrandField<T> = T extends FieldBrand<infer U> ? U: never;
class A extends Base {
    @field()
    public propA: FieldBrand<string> = 'A';
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.0-beta#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMGBTANgEwBQEoBciAhmAJ6IDeAsAFCL2IBOqUIjSoksCi2URjAOYtCAISIBnVABpEAB0Zw5qRlFIBpVKUIBZOJgwAxNFgkAecVIB8sgPoGJERjDlQ4jQgAVFy1aQAiqI7Oru64lLQMUYgQCBJQiBKkALYARnDoiAC8iAAGErYAJBQKSipqmqQAvrkA3JHR9DDAvACE-EIsAHSxYPGMINDuXSgYmBLh1HSN0R3CUD1xUANDjCMm49mUVfXTjVUNjXPdvf2DbmujpgDapb4VWgC6W0lpGbtRO7QHNLQQ6JIJIhLKgIntENcAOSnZbndyQx6ENTKOAtEG7Q6JfiwCDIDYSQgAJVQsUYmDMJFIskpVg+DHiRBxiHmxjG5gAKuyABYwIGoAAeUFQYE2yNQqOBklQVj4PIJiE5cvCYJmiDFiAAklsNX1+JBUOzSMozIrebTMVFmKx2Gq5es2cQgRREBaZtdPIgYEgANZaCVaySa93PAVCkVA1lYUSMEjk8DesBwADuYCsiAA-IgPYQwKgAG4qZ6EfpewSu+g-T7fWi0Az-ASgmF4sbR2OEcAwACOIFBr3S6F26sjmFbIpNaay7MQADJ6M7rlcRzGRY90zn8ypED91QBVMCjzDD8dbKeh4WbYcHsxe4CbndpzM79cFxi7esSIEAQUQZ-DkqkKoMAAAoueCYnIICpOgMC4ncn6EJey7kiWYCCBOiCQp+kK7D8fwAh+wI-oK55AiCgH0CBGxgeCEFQTB8g+KICEbFeKFoVskKiNhNbggyTJCvEeDkbMdqLhImI-LhNDqnoBjoMOHJEWGmwguhxLdjAzDkgA8skMBQCasi+qQEqqWms5sTxTZEFsuZJogn7UU2qS2ag9miEJVlxBkqBdOgcCCHwRrii0RCyGKEqpLIn5dCy+J4LIoixSwCl4LgPEAPQZQ5yVQKl4Q5FMWXRHBxbLKWuzFVUQA)

Comment: I was considering something similar. However we have several similar static members and millions of places where these are used. So replacing them would be a bit of pain. I have tried to use getters on a similar way but getters may not have ```this: TThis``` argument

Comment: Filtering the members is not an issue in the above case. The inherited classes contain nothing else only the decorated field definitions. So ```type ModelFields<T extends Base> = Required<Omit<T, keyof Base>>``` works well

Comment: @ZoltanMagyar getters don't support a `this` parameter .. there is a proposal to support it but it will probably not be implemented any time soon. Without a function there is no way to move forward

Comment: @ZoltanMagyar I thought you might add other members such as methods taht are not decorated. You could filter out methods by filtering out just functions if there are no other fields `I[P] extends (...a: any) => any ? P : never`

Comment: Given there are probably no better solution than the above I accepted this answer.