# How to have a Typescript function return a subclass?

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics, subclass

I'm developing an Entity-Component-System in TypeScript where entities contain a map of their components. `CT` stands for `ComponentType` Here is the code:

```
class Entity {
  components: Map<CT, Component>;

  constructor() {
    this.components = new Map();
  }

  get(componentType: CT): Component {
    return this.components.get(componentType);
  }
}

const enum CT {
  Position,
  Health // etc..
}

class Component {
  type: CT;

  constructor(type: CT) {
    this.type = type;
  }
}

class HealthComponent extends Component {
  amount: number;
  
  constructor() {
    super(CT.Health);

    this.amount = 0;
  }
}
```

The problem is that when I do something like:

```
let healthComponent = new HealthComponent();
healthComponent.amount = 100;

let entity = new Entity();
entity.components.set(healthComponent.type, healthComponent);

let position = entity.get(CT.Health);
console.log(health.amount);
```

I get this error: `Property 'amount' does not exist on type 'Component'`

If I change the `Entity.get` function to instead return `any` like this, then the error goes away:

```
get(componentType: CT): any {
  return this.components.get(componentType);
}
```

But then I no longer get code-completion, which I would like.

Is it possible to have it return the proper type, so I can have the code-completion and error-detection?

Comment: Where is `PositionComponent` used?

Comment: @Vishnudev Good point - Just added that to the example for clarification

Comment: Can you `if (position is PositionComponent) console.log((position as PositionComponent).x)`?

Comment: @DM I would like to avoid that if possible, because I already know the type.

Comment: You know the type, but your compiler doesn't. The `Map` just contains `Component`s which don't have an `x` property. You might be able to try `Map<CT, Component | PositionComponent>` but I doubt that's the correct TS approach.

Comment: Is there any way to re-architect the code such that a call to `get` would be able to return the component of the proper type while also knowing the type? Like maybe something like `entity.get<PositionComponent>()` or something?

Comment: Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34098023/14956277), Try setting the return type of your `Component` constructor? `constructor(type: CT): this { this.type = type; }`. Inherited types should then return their type instead of the parent type.

Comment: I was able to rewrite the code without `Map`. `Map` seems to be problematic in TypeScript. [Code](http://shorturl.at/pyAX6) Check *Abstract Factory* pattern to solve architecture issue.

Comment: @Vishnudev I'm still getting the `property does not exist` error in your linked code snippet

Comment: Yes. It's because you haven't implemented the design/hierarchy of the classes properly. Check the pattern that I mentioned.

Comment: Ah, okay. Reading about it now, thanks.

Comment: @DM I'm getting the error: `Type annotation cannot appear on a constructor definition` error when I try to set the return type of my constructor.

Comment: @RyanPeschel Yeah, I misread the linked post, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Component {
  // error: 'amount' does not exist on type 'Component'
  amount: number; // <-- NOTE: moved amount here from HealthComponent
  type: CT;

  constructor(type: CT) {
    this.type = type;
  }
}

class HealthComponent extends Component {
  // removed amount from here
  
  constructor() {
    super(CT.Health);

    this.amount = 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Nah I have like 100 components I can't just stick everything in the base class. Then the intellisense would just list everything and that's almost as bad as listing nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to hack something together using TypeScript's [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html). It's not ideal but it might work for you:

Let's declare the enum and component classes first:

```
const enum CT {
  Position,
  Health
}

class HealthComponent {
  amount: number;
  
  constructor() {
    this.amount = 0;
  }
}

class PositionComponent {
  position: number;
  
  constructor() {
    this.position = 1;
  }
}
```

Then the conditional type that maps the enum values to component classes:

```
type TypeMapper<T extends CT> = T extends CT.Position 
  ? PositionComponent 
  : HealthComponent;
```

It's a generic type that based on it's type parameter `T` either evaluates to the `PositionComponent` or the `HealthComponent` class.

And now the entity class:

```
class Entity {
  private components: Map<CT, TypeMapper<CT>>;

  constructor() {
    this.components = new Map();
  }

  set<T extends CT>(ct: T, component: TypeMapper<T>) {
    this.components.set(ct, component);
  }

  get<T extends CT>(ct: T): TypeMapper<T> {
    return this.components.get(ct) as any; //a little lie here to shut up the TS compiler
  }
}
```

Now when you instantiate everything, the types should align for you correctly:

```
const entity = new Entity();

entity.set(CT.Health, new HealthComponent());

const health = entity.get(CT.Health);

health.amount //and the amount prop should show up in intellisense correctly.
```

As I said, it's not ideal because it relies on using `any`, also depending on the number of component classes you have, your `TypeMapper` type can become huge, but at least the `Component` base class and `super()` calls to it's constructor are no longer necessary so you win some lines of code there.

Here's the [TS playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=48&ssc=14&pln=42&pc=1#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-S49dHYzAOCwns1Mz1vIHc3sS5X8ARa+IOL5VOooNGgA).

Comment: Will this work with more than two components though? I have around 100

Comment: @RyanPeschel if you type them all out in the `TypeMapper`, it should. You would go `T extends CT.One ? One : T extends CT.Two ? Two : ... T extends CT.NinetyNine ? NinetyNine : Hundred`.

Comment: Uhhh, is this really the best way?