# Typescript -- instantiate child from a static method in base class, with args and referencing other static method

Tags: node.js, typescript, typescript-generics, typescript-class

I am trying to instantiate a child class from a static method in a base class. I want to type my base class correctly rather than using `any` as the return type on all my static methods. I tried the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34098023/typescript-self-referencing-return-type-for-static-methods-in-inheriting-classe?rq=1) but it doesn't work for a static method that references other static methods, or accepts arguments. How can I correctly inherit from a base class in typescript, and still reference other methods and accept arguments?

```
class BaseClass {
  id: string;

  [key: string]: unknown;

  static getName() {
    return this.name.toUpperCase()
  }

  static async find<T extends BaseClass>(this: new (...args: any[]) => T, id: string)
  : Promise<T> {
    const tableName = this.getName();

    const result: GetResult = db.find(tableName, id);

    return new this(result);
  }
}

class Child extends BaseClass {
  name: string;

  static findOne(id: string): Promise<Child> {
    return this.find(id);
  }
}

Child.find('abcd');
```

This causes two different errors

1. `Property 'getName' does not exist on type 'new (...args: any[]) => T'.` (in the `find` method)
2. `Type 'BaseModel' is missing the following properties from type 'Child': name.` (in the return type for `findOne` method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `find` method of the base class you should specify that it expects child class to implement static `getName` method, like this:

```
static async find<T>(this: { new (arg: GetResult): T } & typeof BaseClass, id: string): Promise<T>
```

Particularly `{ new (arg: GetResult): T }` brings you constructor and `typeof BaseClass` brings you static members.

I mocked some missing parts and it typechecks.

```
type GetResult = string;

const db = {
    find: (a: string, b: string) => "bar",
}

class BaseClass {
  id: string = "bzzzz";

  [key: string]: unknown;

  static getName() {
    return 'NAME'
  }

  static async find<T>(this: { new (arg: GetResult): T } & typeof BaseClass, id: string)
  : Promise<T> {
    const tableName = this.getName();

    const result: GetResult = db.find(tableName, id);

    return new this(result);
  }
}

class Child extends BaseClass {
  name: string = "Child";

  static findOne(id: string): Promise<Child> {
    return this.find(id);
  }
}

Child.find('abcd');
```

Comment: I tried to to simplify the implementation to make the question clear. The answer I'm looking for is how to get the typings to work with my implementation, given that my implementation works with normal JS.

Comment: I need to be able to call `this.getName` because my "real life" implementation depends on the name of the child class

Comment: I didn't mark id and name as optional because they aren't optional.

Comment: @JeremyGottfried ok, I see. I edited the answer, hope I understand you correctly. Steel mocked some stuff (because I do not know where to get name, id, db and what is GetResult, but now it uses child getName. Does it look ok now?

Comment: Thank you, it looks like this works! I'm just confused by this: `this: { new (arg: GetResult): T; getName: () => string }`. Why can't I use `T extends BaseClass`? If T extends from BaseClass, doesn't that guarantee that it has the `getName` method?

Comment: @JeremyGottfried nice catch, I improved the answer a little bit

Comment: It would be awesome if that works, but now I get this error if I call `Child.find('abcd')`: `The 'this' context of type 'typeof Child' is not assignable to method's 'this' of type '{ new (arg: GetResult): Child } & typeof BaseClass'. Type 'typeof Child' is not assignable to type 'typeof BaseClass'.`

Comment: @JeremyGottfried Hm, its weird. What version of typescript do you use? It works for me in typescript sandbox https://www.typescriptlang.org/play (full link is too large, just copy solution there). Could you please check if you copied updated solution correctly? I also tried it localy, works just fine.

Comment: I'm on TS v3.9.3. I copied everything except abstract class. What is `abstract class Foo` doing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231962/discussion-between-artyom-kozhemiakin-and-jeremy-gottfried).