# How to get the type of implementing class as a method response?

Tags: typescript

Example:

```
class Parent {
  static thingy(): Parent {
    // do something
    return this;
  }
}

class Child1  extends Parent {
}

class Child2 extends Parent {
}
```

The goal is for `Child1.thingy()` to return a type of `Child1`. And for `Child2.thingy()` to return a type of `Child2`.

Currently the best I can come up with is:

```
static <T extends Parent>thingy(): T { ... }
```

and invoking it as

`Child1.thingy<Child1>()`

The practical use case here is an API abstraction that has the ability to impersonate, and every single object that extends this API abstraction (talking about their own endpoint) can invoke `.asAdmin()` to invoke that API as an admin, and not the impersonated account. The thing is I still need to chain .asAdmin() with the rest of the endpoint-specific code. Just as a practical example of where something like this may be used.

Trying to see if I can avoid the extra typing information.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Self-referencing return type for static methods in inheriting classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34098023/typescript-self-referencing-return-type-for-static-methods-in-inheriting-classe)

Comment: What does `thingy()`? Why does it need to return the type of the class used to invoke it? How is its return type used?

Comment: @jonrsharpe yeah that was it.