Why does adding a typescript return type break my function chaining?
I am seeing a weird behavior and would appreciate some help. Here is my class:
export class KtorHttpAdapter {

    static application: IRatingUseCase

   public static from (app: IRatingUseCase): KtorHttpAdapter{
      KtorHttpAdapter.application = app;
      return this;
   }

   public static performSomeFunction (value: number): number {
     return KtorHttpAdapter.application.rateAndResult(value)
   }
}

Here is how I am calling the KtorHttpAdapter class:
const application: IRatingUseCase = new RatingApplication(rater);

KtorHttpAdapter.from(application).performSomeFunction(5);

and here is the error I am getting:
Property 'performSomeFunction' does not exist on type 'KtorHttpAdapter'. Did you mean to access the static member 'KtorHttpAdapter.performSomeFunction' instead?
If I remove the KtorHttpAdapter return type that's declared on my from() method in the KtorHttpAdapter class, then error goes away and my code compiles and works as expected.
Am I missing something?

Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34098023/self-referencing-return-type-for-static-methods-in-inheriting-classes

public static from (app: IRatingUseCase): KtorHttpAdapter {

The return type KtorHttpAdapter would mean an instance of the KtorHttpAdapter class. But an instance of the class will not have the static properties, just the instance properties (if any).
Instead, you want to return type of the constructor function used to build KtorHttpAdapters. This is the type that includes the static methods. You can get that type with the typeof keyword:
public static from (app: IRatingUseCase): typeof KtorHttpAdapter {

Playground link

If I remove the KtorHttpAdapter return type that's declared on my from() method in the KtorHttpAdapter class, then error goes away and my code compiles and works as expected.

One tip if you see something like this again, where the inferred type works but your explicit type does not. In most IDE's you can mouse over a variable and it will show you the types. So if you mouse over the function name, you should be able to see what the correct type is. For example, in this screenshot my mouse is over "from"

You can then copy the type that the IDE shows and put it in the explicit code
